# How to group the files in a single line based on a string value in Python?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

**The data in input file is of this format**

```
XD56783E
clutch.pdf
brake0.pdf
brake1.pdf
XT6111GT
clutch.pdf
brake0.pdf
brake1.pdf
brake2.pdf
brake3.pdf
```

**The expected output should be as**

```
XD56783E    clutch.pdf  brake0.pdf  brake1.pdf
XT6111GT    clutch.pdf  brake0.pdf  brake1.pdf  brake2.pdf  brake3.pdf
```

The below code does not give the desired output as above.

Wrote a simple vague code:

```py
check_filetype = ['c','b']
revisedData = None
temp = None

for keyvalue in open("sampl.txt"):
     if 'X' in keyvalue[0]:
        revisedData = keyvalue.strip() + ' '
     else:
        if 'c' or 'b' in keyvalue[0]:
            temp = keyvalue.strip()
            revisedData = revisedData + ' ' + temp                  
print(revisedData)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code doesn't work because every time the program finds a line starting with `X`, `revisedData` will be assigned a new value and the previous value will be overlapped. To fix that, you can just change the line

```
revisedData = None
...
if 'X' in keyvalue[0]:
    revisedData = keyvalue.strip() + ' '
```

to

```
revisedData = ""
...
if 'X' in keyvalue[0]:
    revisedData += keyvalue.strip() + ' '
```

So that the new value will be added to the end of the string. But for operating with strings, I recommend you to manage it with an array as it's more efficient to change the values.

Apart from that, instead of doing `if 'X' in keyvalue[0]`, you can use `startswith` instead to achieve the same effect. Another problem with your code is that after each line that starts with `X` there should be a new line. So the revised code is as follows:

```
check_filetype = ['c', 'b']

revisedData = []

for keyvalue in open("sampl.txt"):
    if keyvalue.startswith('X'):
        # Note that the newline is in the front of the string, because you want the elements that follow to be in the same line
        revisedData.append("\n" + keyvalue.strip())
    else:
        if keyvalue.startswith(('c','b')):
            revisedData.append(keyvalue.strip())

# Passing the array to join " " will create a result with all the elements in the array separated by " "
revisedData = " ".join(revisedData).strip()

print(revisedData)
```

Output

```
XD56783E clutch.pdf brake0.pdf brake1.pdf 
XT6111GT clutch.pdf brake0.pdf brake1.pdf brake2.pdf brake3.pdf
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `pandas` library to read the data in and transform as required with `.groupby` and `' '.join` to bring the group together. The code to create the groups returns `True` or `False` if the string contains a capital letter `X`. `True` and `False` are `boolean` values that actually represent `1` and `0` respectively, so when you take the cumulative sum of `[True, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False]`, you get `[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2]`. For example, to calculate the last 2, the calculation is `(1 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 1 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0)` while the calculation for the second `1` is `1 + 0`. You end up with group `1` and group `2` with this sample data, which you then `.groupby` in order to join the the values in the different rows into one string as desired.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('sampl.txt', header=None)
df = df.groupby(df[0].str.contains('X').cumsum().astype(str))[0].apply(' '.join)
df.to_csv('sampl.txt', index=False)
df

Out[1]:
0
1            XD56783E clutch.pdf brake0.pdf brake1.pdf
2    XT6111GT clutch.pdf brake0.pdf brake1.pdf brak...
```

Comment: Tried this approach and it worked!. Thank you